# GDB отладка ядра в qemu. Как правильно загрузить файлы с отладочной информацией?

Tags: gcc, отладка, gdb, ядро

Всем привет. Занимаюсь разработкой простой ос. Столкнулся с проблемой: не получается загрузить файлы с отладочной информацией в gdb. 
Имеется десяток файлов, которые компилируются в отдельные .o файлы, а затем линкуются в один бинарник.

Командная строка g++

```
g++ -c -g -m32 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
```

Командная строка ld

```
ld -T src/kernel/link.ld -o bin/kernel.bin $(KERNEL_OBJ_LINK_LIST)
```

link.ld

```
ENTRY(kernel_start)
SECTIONS 
{
    . = 0x00100000;
    ___kern_mem_start = .;
    .text : 
    {
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata : 
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
    .data : 
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : 
    {
        *(.bss)
    }
    ___kern_mem_end = .;
    _mem_null = .;
}
```

Теперь, запуская gdb и присоединяясь к qemu я хочу поставить брейкпоинт на какую-либо функцию, но не могу так как gdb пишет, что debug information не загружена. Как мне загрузить эту информацию? Я пробовал указывать gdb

```
file bin/kernel.bin
```

но gdb пишет что не может найти там отладочную информацию несмотря на флаг -g в g++.

**Update**.

Загружаю символы из подготовленного через objdump файла. При загрузке всё равно пишет, что символов не было загружено, но при этом я могу поставить брейкпоинт на функцию. Проблема теперь в том, что этот брейкпоинт не срабатывает. Есть идеи в чём проблема?

Comment: А [вот это](http://wiki.osdev.org/Kernel_Debugging#Use_gdb_with_Qemu) уже пробовали?

Comment: Да, конечно. Я именно так и делаю.

Comment: Ну, тогда остается надеяться, что кто-нибудь уже прошел этот путь *на практике* и подскажет, что и как (но, ищите и в др. местах, похоже тут таких гуру нет).

Comment: На это и надеялся. Но видимо никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

После долгого изучения дампов gdb я понял в чём была ошибка. Загрузчик загружал подготовительный сектор ядра и само ядро в 0x100:0x0(абсолютный адрес 0x1000). В то же время в скрипте линкера указан отсчёт адресов от 0x100000. Соответственно в отладочную информацию попадали адреса функций и переменных отсчитываемые от 0x100000. Исправил скрипт и всё заработало. Gdb жаловался на плохой отладочный файл. Пофиксил сменой формата отладочной информации (-gstabs). Затрудняюсь объяснить почему именно этот формат работает т.к. выбирал подбором с этой страницы https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Кусок моего мейкфала. Может кому-нибудь пригодится. После линковки убираем в отдельный файл отладочную информацию из бинарника утилитой objcopy.

```
KERNEL_COMPILER=gcc
KERNEL_DEFAULT_GCC_FLAGS=-m32 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -gstabs
KERNEL_OBJ_LINK_LIST=$(CRTI_OBJ) \
                     $(CRTBEGIN_OBJ) \
                     obj/kernel_start.o \
                     obj/kernel_main.o \
                     obj/gdt_flush.o \
                     obj/gdt.o obj/kdbg.o \
                     obj/idt.o \
                     obj/idt_impl.o \
                     obj/kmem.o \
                     $(CRTEND_OBJ) \
                     $(CRTN_OBJ) \
                     obj/kernel_debug_end.o

bin/kernel.bin:
    nasm -f elf32 src/kernel/kernel_start.asm -o obj/kernel_start.o -l lst/kernel/kernel_start.lst

    $(KERNEL_COMPILER) -c -o obj/kernel_main.o src/kernel/kernel_main.cpp $(KERNEL_DEFAULT_GCC_FLAGS)

    $(KERNEL_COMPILER) -c -o obj/gdt.o src/kernel/hal/gdt.cpp $(KERNEL_DEFAULT_GCC_FLAGS)
    nasm -f elf32 src/kernel/hal/gdt_flush.asm -o obj/gdt_flush.o -l lst/kernel/hal/gdt_flush.lst
    $(KERNEL_COMPILER) -c -o obj/idt.o src/kernel/hal/idt.cpp $(KERNEL_DEFAULT_GCC_FLAGS)
    nasm -f elf32 src/kernel/hal/idt_impl.asm -o obj/idt_impl.o -l lst/kernel/hal/idt_impl.lst

    $(KERNEL_COMPILER) -c -o obj/kmem.o src/kernel/kmem.cpp $(KERNEL_DEFAULT_GCC_FLAGS)

    $(KERNEL_COMPILER) -c -o obj/kdbg.o src/kernel/kdbg.cpp $(KERNEL_DEFAULT_GCC_FLAGS)

    nasm -f elf32 src/kernel/kernel_debug_end.asm -o obj/kernel_debug_end.o -l lst/kernel/kernel_debug_end.lst

    ld -g -T src/kernel/link.ld -o bin/kernel.bin -Map lst/kernel/kernel_map.map $(KERNEL_OBJ_LINK_LIST)

    objcopy --only-keep-debug bin/kernel.bin debug_info/kernel.debug
    objcopy --strip-debug bin/kernel.bin bin/kernel.bin
```